# SUM and GROUP BY 2 different values

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, aggregate-functions

I want to SUM grouping 2 different values in a single column.

I have this table

[image]

And I want to group CLASS A with B and then Class B, like this

[image]

Is this possible in SQL?

Comment: What's you dbms?

Comment: Create a second table  as class, displayname.   Join to this table on class and select/group by displayname.   Easier to leave this logic in a table than in code.

Answer (score 2):

You can try a `CASE`, that returns `'A-B'` when `class` is `'A'` or `'B'`.

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN class IN ('A', 'B') THEN
           'A-B'
         ELSE
           class
       END class,
       sum(budget)
       FROM elbat
       GROUP BY CASE
                  WHEN class IN ('A', 'B') THEN
                    'A-B'
                  ELSE
                    class
                END;
```

Comment: Without the constraint of knowing the specific flavor of SQL, this answer seems plausible.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way to to this would be to use CASE Statements.

See docs here: https://community.modeanalytics.com/sql/tutorial/sql-case/

e.g.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CLASS IN ('A','B') THEN 'A-B'
       ELSE CLASS
       END AS GROUPED_CLASS, 
       SUM(BUDGET)
FROM budgets
GROUP BY GROUPED_CLASS
```

The above query should give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 approaches here...first is to use case statements as others have said.  This is a code based solution, meaning if there are future alterations you need to alter it in the code (and on multiple reports if this logic is used elsewhere).

The alternative is to make a table that manages this relation.   Create a table (i will call dim_class) with two columns class and display_name and use this table to manage the relation.

Class, display_name

A, a-b

B, a-b

C, C

```
Select display_name, sum(budget)
From class inner join dim_class on class.class = dim_class
Group by display_name
```

If this is one shot code, id go with a quick case statement.   If you are reusing the logic or there are a lot of classes, the table is far easier to maintain.  You can also double up on what buckets they go in...

Class, display_name

A, a-b

B, a-b

C, c only

A, c and a

C, c and a